# Python-polars: how to multiply each element in a list with a value in a different column?

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe with a certain number of groups, containing a weight column and a list of values, which can be of arbitrary length, so for example:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Group": ["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"],
        "Weight": [100.0, 200.0, 300.0],
        "Vals": [[0.5, 0.5, 0.8],[0.5, 0.5, 0.8], [0.7, 0.9]]
    }
)
```

```
┌────────┬────────┬─────────────────┐
│ Group  ┆ Weight ┆ Vals            │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---             │
│ str    ┆ f64    ┆ list[f64]       │
╞════════╪════════╪═════════════════╡
│ Group1 ┆ 100.0  ┆ [0.5, 0.5, 0.8] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Group2 ┆ 200.0  ┆ [0.5, 0.5, 0.8] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Group3 ┆ 300.0  ┆ [0.7, 0.9]      │
└────────┴────────┴─────────────────┘
```

My goal is to calculate a 'weighted' column, which would be the multiple of each item in the values list with the value in the weight column:

```
┌────────┬────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ Group  ┆ Weight ┆ Vals            ┆ Weighted        │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---             ┆ ---             │
│ str    ┆ f64    ┆ list[f64]       ┆ list[i64]       │
╞════════╪════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ Group1 ┆ 100.0  ┆ [0.5, 0.5, 0.8] ┆ [50, 50, 80]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Group2 ┆ 200.0  ┆ [0.5, 0.5, 0.8] ┆ [100, 100, 160] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Group3 ┆ 300.0  ┆ [0.7, 0.9]      ┆ [210, 270]      │
└────────┴────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I've tried a few different things:

```
df.with_columns([
        pl.col("Vals").arr.eval(pl.element() * 3).alias("Weight1"), #Multiplying with literal works
        pl.col("Vals").arr.eval(pl.element() * pl.col("Weight")).alias("Weight2"), #Does not work
        pl.col("Vals").arr.eval(pl.element() * pl.col("Unknown")).alias("Weight3"), #Unknown columns give same value
        pl.col("Vals").arr.eval(pl.col("Vals") * pl.col("Weight")).alias("Weight4"), #Same effect
        # pl.col('Vals') * 3 -> gives an error
]
)
```

```
┌────────┬────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Group  ┆ Weight ┆ Vals       ┆ Weight1    ┆ Weight2      ┆ Weight3      ┆ Weight4            │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---                │
│ str    ┆ f64    ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]  ┆ list[f64]    ┆ list[f64]    ┆ list[f64]          │
╞════════╪════════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ Group1 ┆ 100.0  ┆ [0.5, 0.5, ┆ [1.5, 1.5, ┆ [0.25, 0.25, ┆ [0.25, 0.25, ┆ [0.25, 0.25, 0.64] │
│        ┆        ┆ 0.8]       ┆ 2.4]       ┆ 0.64]        ┆ 0.64]        ┆                    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Group2 ┆ 200.0  ┆ [0.5, 0.5, ┆ [1.5, 1.5, ┆ [0.25, 0.25, ┆ [0.25, 0.25, ┆ [0.25, 0.25, 0.64] │
│        ┆        ┆ 0.8]       ┆ 2.4]       ┆ 0.64]        ┆ 0.64]        ┆                    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Group3 ┆ 300.0  ┆ [0.7, 0.9] ┆ [2.1, 2.7] ┆ [0.49, 0.81] ┆ [0.49, 0.81] ┆ [0.49, 0.81]       │
└────────┴────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Unless I'm not understanding it correctly, it seems like you're unable to access columns outside of the list from within the eval function. Perhaps there might be a way to use list comprehension within the statement, but that doesn't really seem like a neat solution.

What would be the recommended approach here? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT - Polars update:

As of the latest version of Polars, this is now a the correct syntax:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Group": ["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"],
        "Weight": [100.0, 200.0, 300.0],
        "Vals": [[0.5, 0.5, 0.8],[0.5, 0.5, 0.8], [0.7, 0.9]]
    }
)

(df
    .explode('Vals')
    .with_columns(Weighted = pl.col('Weight')*pl.col('Vals'))
    .groupby('Group')
    .agg(
        pl.col('Weight').first(),                                                                                                             
        pl.col('Vals'),
        pl.col('Weighted')
        )                                                                                                 
)
```

#### Old answer:

```py
(df
    .explode('Vals')
    .with_columns(Weighted = pl.col('Weight')*pl.col('Vals'))
    .groupby('Group')
    .agg([
        pl.col('Weight').first(),                                                                                                             
        pl.col('Vals').list(),
        pl.col('Weighted').list()
        ])                                                                                                 
)
```

Comment: It does, thank you! Fyi, between this one and @alexp 's, this solution seems to be around 3x faster on my real data.

Comment: The behavior of `agg` has changed. You should no longer call `.list()` on the expressions within the `agg` call. @MYK could you update your answer?

Comment: If the group column wasn't present here, would I need to introduce a separate dummy column to use for the groupby operation afterward? No smart way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1):

So you can solve this in two ways. To be honest I don't know which one is better, I haven't tested for performance or RAM usage.

## Algorithm 1

We can put both columns in a struct and then apply a custom function on them. (Which is explained in the Documentation [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html#combining-multiple-column-values))

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

def weighted_list(ls, weight):
    return(list(np.array(ls) * weight))

(df.with_columns([pl.struct(["Weight", "Vals"])
                  .apply(lambda x: weighted_list(x["Vals"], x["Weight"]))])
)
```

## Algorithm 2

So in this case you have to be careful that your columns "Group", "Weight" are unique. So if you have two entries for example with Group3 and Weight 300.

```
(df.explode("Vals")
    .with_column((pl.col("Vals") * pl.col("Weight")).alias("Weighted"))
    .groupby(["Group", "Weight"])
    .agg([pl.list("Vals"), pl.list("Weighted")])
)
```